# Azure Microsoft Monitoring Agent failing to provision with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to install the MMA agent as part of a VM deployment using Terraform. I am sure the failure is due to the syntax of the extension I am using but I have had no luck determining what it should be. The agent installs but will not join the Log Analytics workspace.  I am storing the workspace ID and the Primary Key in Key Vault and passing them into Terraform at execution time. From the extension logs on the VM, it looks like it is getting the correct workspace ID but I can't tell if it is receiving the key correctly.  Below is the Terraform syntax I using:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "lawks-test" {
  name = "MMA_${azurerm_virtual_machine.test.name}"
  location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.test.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
  type                 = "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent"
  type_handler_version = "1.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
        {
          "workspaceId": "${data.terraform_remote_state.corerg.on_workspace_id}"
        }
        SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
        {
          "workspaceKey": "${var.on_laws_key}"
        }
        PROTECTED_SETTINGS
```

Below is what is shown in one of the extension log files:

```
11/19/2018 9:43:51 PM +00:00 Managed Service Identity extension (Microsoft.ManagedIdentity.ManagedIdentityExtensionForWindows) not found on this box, automaticManagement will be skipped on this box.
11/19/2018 9:43:51 PM +00:00 HandlerConfig found, default config will be override, CloudType changed to 1
11/19/2018 9:43:51 PM +00:00 GET http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01 with requestId 9a17250a-bfd0-4e4b-b9d3-aa4ceaf9007e
11/19/2018 9:43:52 PM +00:00 azureResourceId from metadata service.
11/19/2018 9:43:52 PM +00:00 automaticManagement not enabled.
11/19/2018 9:43:52 PM +00:00 systemWorkspace provision failed due to AutomaticManagementNotEnabled
11/19/2018 9:43:52 PM +00:00 only configSpecifiedWorkspace available.
11/19/2018 9:43:52 PM +00:00 SettingFile changed, re-apply configuration.
11/19/2018 9:43:52 PM +00:00 Adding workspace /subscriptions/<my_subscription_id>/resourcegroups/resource_group/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/my-workspace.
11/19/2018 9:43:53 PM +00:00 Unknown error during enable command : System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , String , String , Int32 )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring.MicrosoftMonitoringAgent.Extension.MMAConfigHelper.AddCloudWorkspace(String workspaceId, String workspaceKey, Nullable`1 cloudType)
   at Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring.MicrosoftMonitoringAgent.Extension.EnableProgram.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: you are supposed to pass in strings to those, what are you passing in to them? also, take a look here, looks okay to me https://medium.com/modern-stack/bootstrap-a-vm-to-azure-automation-dsc-using-terraform-f2ba41d25cd2, except maybe `SETTINGS` and `PROTECTED_SETTINGS` should be at the start of the string exactly (closing ones)

Comment: You can check if the agent which used to interact between Azure and the vm works well.

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks for the link on DSC...has some useful info in it...just not for the problem I am trying to solve. I am passing in strings...you can see in the log file that it is getting my workspace ID that I pass in.

Comment: i dont see a guid anywhere in the output, so wont be able to tell. format the terraform file properly, to start with

Comment: @4c74356b41 I did not understand what you meant in your original comment with regards to the formatting. What is wrong with the formatting I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for those that replied. I discovered what the issue is by trying to do a manual install. The azurerm_log_analytics_workspace resouce has 2 attributes that relate to ID:

```
id - The Log Analytics Workspace ID
```

and

```
workspace_id - The Workspace (or Customer) ID for the Log Analytics Workspace
```

I was incorrectly trying to use "id" which is the wrong one. Once I used the "workspace_id" attribute, the install worked fine...with no changes to the formatting of the Terraform code.

The one thing I have often found lacking about Terraform is the documentation.

Comment: you can  accept you own answer and can consider upvoting my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

just tested it, here's a working example:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "acctestRG1"
  location = "UK West"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = "acctvn"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
  name                 = "acctsub"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}"
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "test" {
  name                = "acctni"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.test.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "test" {
  name                  = "acctvm1z"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.test.id}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS2_v2"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter-smalldisk"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname1"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!qwe"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {
    provision_vm_agent = "true"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
  name                 = "omsagent"
  location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.test.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring"
  type                 = "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent"
  type_handler_version = "1.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
        {
          "workspaceId": "workspaceId"
        }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
        {
          "workspaceKey": "workspaceKey"
        }
PROTECTED_SETTINGS # NOTICE THIS STARTS EXACTLY AT THE START OF THE STRING
}
```

if that doesnt help, the problem is in how you pass the workspaceKey (so you are missing part of the key, or something like that)